# Is there a simple way to transfer uncommited work-in-progress changes from one computer to another?

Tags: git

I often start some work on my desktop PC and then finish it on a laptop. When I need to switch I usually commit and push the broken mess to my upstream branch and pull it from the other computer. This usually ends up creating a long chain of useless commits with creative messages such as "wip", "asd" and "gsdnfsudkfnsdunf". I can't help the feeling that I'm missing something here. Is there an easy way to transfer those changes from one computer to another without creating all those commits?

Comment: Are you the only one using the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a private topic. Assuming you'll be delivering to `master`, but really just substitute your target branch. `git checkout master && git branch my-topic && git checkout my-topic` commit as you like, it won't matter.

Push and pull from the server as needed. When you're done do a final `git rebase -i master` and clean yourself up.

Comment: I followed those instructions but after I created the temporary branch and then I did rebase how do I have to push to the repo? Do I have to do `git push origin my-topic` or `git push origin master`?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good scenario for branching :)

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow/